# issue with opencv_highgui242.dll opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-8, 64-bit

i'm new in openCV. I configure it with this tutorial `http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/` but I use `win8`. when i wrote this basic code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    IplImage* frame = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        cvNamedWindow("Sample Program", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Sample Program", frame);
        int c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { exit(0); }
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);



    return 0;
}
```

a dialog box shown with this message:

```
    opencv_highgui242.dll is missing from your computer.
 try re installing the program to fix this problem.
```

what can i do for that?

```
EDIT:
I solve that with adding library to my project path but i have new error:


the application was unable start correctly(0xc000007b). click ok to close the application.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:
the problem was with `environment Variables`:
i created new variables and copy values to them but i must edit path variable`(if exiting)` or create new variable with name path`(if not exist)` and copy:

`C:\OpenCV-2.4.2\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin\;C:\OpenCV2.4.2\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\; to that if path exist`

```
 and copy  ;C:\OpenCV-2.4.2\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin\;C:\OpenCV-2.4.2\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\; if not exist.
```